# How to select a range relative to current time NOW() using Index Scan rather than Seq Scan?

Tags: postgresql

In the below query:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE appointment.starttime BETWEEN 1620133200 AND 1620207000
```

Where the column `starttime` has an index, the `EXPLAIN` statment for the above query shows that it will use Index Scan, which is perfect so far.

However, that's only when I'm providing the numbers `1620133200` and `1620207000` hardcoded in the query. But what I need to do is to get them relative to the current time instead.

So I tried the next query:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM appointment 
WHERE appointment.starttime BETWEEN 
extract(epoch from now()) - 3600 AND
extract(epoch from now()) + 3600
```

However, now it shows that it no longer uses Index Scan. It shows Seq Scan instead. This is really bad because we have hundreds of thousands of appointments and this query is expected to be executed many times in parallel.

I tried different attempts such as the following query:

```
EXPLAIN

WITH range AS (
  SELECT
    extract(epoch from now()) - 3600  AS _from,
    extract(epoch from now()) + 3600  AS _to
)

SELECT
  *
FROM appointment
CROSS JOIN range
WHERE appointment.starttime BETWEEN _from AND _to
```

But unfortunately, it still uses Seq Scan on the appointments table rather than using the index.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** for the second query as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: I thought about including the full results of the explain statement but it discloses the exact number of records in the database which I'm not authorized to share. Also, this is mainly a simplified pseudo query just to focus on the problem while removing any other distracting details

Comment: it is really hard w/o query plan and the table schema. What time starttime is? Is it a timestamp? An integer? `extract (epoch ...)` may give floating number results, what typecasts are happening within the query planner?
I do second the schema/plan inclusion, otherwise it is just guessing game

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @EvgeniyChekan starttime is a bigint containing an epoch timestamp.  "what typecasts are happening" That's a very good question

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by @Evgeniy, `extract(epoch from now())` returns a floating number. And it turns out that even query as simple as the below query still uses Seq Scan just because the index column is an integer type (bigint) while the values it's being compared to are floating points.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT FROM appointment WHERE starttime = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW());
```

> Results: Seq Scan on appointment  (cost=... rows=... width=...)
> Filter: ((starttime)::double precision = date_part('epoch'::text,
> now()))

But if I simply cast it as an integer first:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT FROM appointments2 WHERE starttime = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())::INTEGER;
```

> Bitmap Heap Scan on appointment  (cost=... rows=... width=...)
> Recheck Cond: (starttime = (date_part('epoch'::text, now()))::integer)
> ->  Bitmap Index Scan on appointment_starttime_idx  (cost=... rows=... width=...)
> Index Cond: (starttime = (date_part('epoch'::text, now()))::integer)